# Webcomponents: attributeChangedCallback not fired

Tags: javascript, web-component

Here is a basic hello world web component. The attributeChangedCallback does not get triggered when the attribute "who" is changed. Check the fiddle

```
MyElementProto.attributeChangedCallback = function(attr, oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log('attributeChangedCallback triggered');
        if (attr === 'who') {
            this.setWho(newVal);
        }
    };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y3kj81nz/5/

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method:

```
window.changeWhoAttr = function() {
    var el = document.querySelector('#custom-tag');
    el.setAttribute('who', 'Universe'); // Instead of el.who = 'Universe'
    console.log('changeWhoAttr triggered');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3kj81nz/6/)